# Matching all excerpts which starts and ends with specific words

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching, match

I have a text which looks like:

```
some non interesting part
trans-top
body of first excerpt
trans-bottom
next non interesting part
trans-top
body of second excerpt
trans-bottom
non interesting part
```

And I want to extract all excerpts starting with trans-top and ending with trans-bottom into an array. I tried that:

```
match(/(?=trans-top)(.|\s)*/g)
```

to find strings witch starts with trans-top. And it works. Now I want to specify the end:

```
match(/(?=trans-top)(.|\s)*(?=trans-bottom)/g)
```

and it doesn't. Firebug gives me an error:

> regular expression too complex

I tried many other ways, but I can't find working solution... I'm shure I made some stupid mistake:(.

Comment: Just for your information, on Chrome the result of your complex regexp is `["trans-topbody of first excerpt"]` (no errors).

Comment: Your match would contain `trans-top`, but  not `trans-bottom`.  Do you want the meta-data or not?

Comment: For now it doesn't matter. I need all parts, with meta or without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works pretty well, but it's not all in one regex:

```
var test = "some non interesting part\ntrans-top\nbody of first excerpt\ntrans-bottom\nnext non interesting part\ntrans-top\nbody of second excerpt\ntrans-bottom\nnon interesting part";

var matches = test.match(/(trans-top)([\s\S]*?)(trans-bottom)/gm);
for(var i=0; i<matches.length; i++) {
    matches[i] = matches[i].replace(/^trans-top|trans-bottom$/gm, '');
}

console.log(matches);
```

If you don't want the leading and trailing linebreaks, change the inner loop to:

```
matches[i] = matches[i].replace(/^trans-top[\s\S]|[\s\S]trans-bottom$/gm, '');
```

That should eat the linebreaks.

Comment: I don't think it can, because JavaScript doesn't support lookahead and lookbehind in the regex.  So, you are forced to include the (trans-top) and (trans-bottom) in the results.  I tried it with non-capturing groups, but that doesn't help.  You can easily skip the removal of the (trans-top) and (trans-bottom) if you don't care.

Answer (score 1):

This tested function uses one regex and loops through picking out the contents of each match placing them all in an array which is returned:

```js
function getParts(text) {
    var a = [];
    var re = /trans-top\s*([\S\s]*?)\s*trans-bottom/g;
    var m = re.exec(text);
    while (m != null) {
        a.push(m[1]);
        m = re.exec(text);
    }
    return a;
}
```

It also filters out any lealding and trailing whitespace surrounding each match contents.